# Calculating shortest path between 2 nodes with mandatory points in the middle

Tags: java, algorithm, search, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm trying to solve a problem in a **bidrectional weighted** graph that represents a Metro Service, with around 300 nodes and 700 edges.

The nodes are defined by a metro station and the edges are Strings with the info of the line they belong to and the time (being the edge's weight) it takes to travel in that edge.

I have to determine the fastest way between 2 stations, given a list of **unordered** (if they were ordered a permutation of shortest paths between all the stations would be enough) mandatory stations, and it can go through other stations aswell

After I searched on the issue, I saw some suggestions of creating a sub-graph + applying a DFS. So I created a graph with the beginning station + mandatory stations + end station as the new vertexes, and the edges with the info of the shortest path between each station + the time it takes to travel.

The problem I have now is the following: How do I apply a DFS on this new sub-graph that makes the last visited station forcibly the one i have as a destination?

Sorry for the long question!

Comment: will the graph contain cycle?

Comment: No, it would be a tsp otherwise but I just want to get from a to b passing some required stations in the middle

Answer (score 1):

I have another idea. Since the graph is acyclic graph, we can split the mandatory node (except source and destination node) into two node (**A** to **A<sub>start</sub>** and **A<sub>end</sub>**) and set an edge between them and set the weight as -infinity. All incoming edge to mandatory node **A** will be connected to **A<sub>start</sub>** and all outgoing edge from mandatory node **A** will be came out from **A<sub>end</sub>**. Finally we will run a dijkstra algorithm for source node to destination node. Since we set an -infinite weight in mandatory node, dijkstra is bound to go through them to minimize the cost. Also as the the graph is acyclic graph, we don't have to worry about negative cycle.

[image]

Comment: You can't use Dijkstra with negative edge weights, that's one of the constraints/assumptions.

Comment: @MandisaW the graph is acyclic graph than means it has no cycle. in that case you can use negative edge

Comment: OP doesn't specify an acyclic graph. The sample case is of a train/metro system, and several of those IRL have ring structures (e.g. Tokyo).

Answer (score 0):

There's something you need to define for your problem first : are the mandatory stations the *only* stations that you need to visit in order to get to the destination? Or are there other unknown stations in between that aren't mandatory but may be required in the shortest path?

Assuming this graph contains cycles :

If the list of mandatory stations are all the stations that you will need to get to the destination, you can solve this using Dijkstra's algorithm on the subgraph of all the mandatory nodes.

In the other case, it would be more complicated (NP-hard in fact) See this answer for a more in-depth solution : [Shortest path that traverses a list of required edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130147/shortest-path-that-traverses-a-list-of-required-edges)

Comment: It could have more stations that aren't mandatory (per say, If one of the obrigatory stations doesn't have a direct connection, the stations required to get there need to be included aswell). However, each of my edges on the sub graph have the info of the path between them(the element is a linked list of stations) + its cost as the edge's weight